# I didn't get any notifications when I touched on tabbar items

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, key-value-observing

I have UITabbarCoo=ntroller application. I added an observer and I'm waiting for any notifications. I didn't get any notifications when I touched on tabbar items.

```
[self.tabBarController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"selectedIndex" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:@"changedTabbarIndex"];

 - (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
 NSString *action = (NSString*)context; 
 if([action isEqualToString:@"changedTabbarIndex"])
     {
     }
 }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but is there a reason you can't instead declare yourself as the UITabBarController's delegate and implement "tabBarController:didSelectViewController:" to respond to selected view controller changes?

Comment: Well, for one, it "is not called when your code changes the tab bar contents programmatically".  It would be convenient not to have to handle that separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed the same thing. I assume that this is a bug in the UITabBarController implementation. Note that using a key path of `selectedViewController` instead of `selectedIndex` does cause KVO notifications to be fired.

But be careful. If your UITabBarController has a **UIMoreNavigationController** (for the "More" tab), you will get the KVO notification when the user selects the "More" tab, but you *won't* get any notifications when the user selects a child viewcontroller of the UIMoreNavigationController. This is because the UIMoreNavigationController is a separate view controller, so when you select one of its child view controllers, the UITabBarController's `selectedViewController` isn't changing – it's actually the UIMoreNavigationController's `topViewController` that changes.

It would be great if you could then observe the UIMoreNavigationController's `topViewController` property in addition to the UITabBarController's `selectedViewController` property, but this property does not appear to cause KVO notifications to be fired either. However, you *can* set a delegate on the UIMoreNavigationController and implement the `navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` method.

**Summary:** observe the `selectedViewController` property of the UITabBarController, and if your application has a "More" tab, set a delegate on the tab bar controller's `moreNavigationController` property.

Comment: Note: changing tabs programmatically seems NOT to cause the KVO notification to be fired, either.

Comment: @croald That's pretty standard. KVO notifications are not fired for many UIKit view/view controller properties when the property is modified programmatically. Generally, it's because you already know that the property is being modified. It's a pain sometimes, but it does prevent certain kinds of feedback loops.